# Why is Rename-Item and Copy-Item only working with Start-Sleep in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Strange behaviour when renaming and copying files and folders with PowerShell:

1. Naive approach (**not working** as expected)

   ```
   Rename-Item \\share\to\Folder \\share\to\FolderOld
   Copy-Item \\share\from\Folder \\share\to\Folder -Recurse -Force 
   Remove-Item \\share\to\FolderOld
   ```

   Observation: `\\share\to\Folder` is empty
2. Add some sleep of 10 seconds (**not working** as expected)

   ```
   Rename-Item \\share\to\Folder \\share\to\FolderOld
   Start-Sleep -s 10
   Copy-Item \\share\from\Folder \\share\to\Folder -Recurse -Force 
   Remove-Item \\share\to\FolderOld
   ```

   Observation: `\\share\to\Folder` is still empty
3. Sleep for more than 10 seconds (**working!!!!**)

   ```
   Rename-Item \\share\to\Folder \\share\to\FolderOld
   Start-Sleep -s 30
   Copy-Item \\share\from\Folder \\share\to\Folder -Recurse -Force 
   Remove-Item \\share\to\FolderOld
   ```

   Observation: `\\share\to\Folder` is filled with the contents of `\\share\from\Folder` as expected.

**Question**:
Why is approach 3. working?

**Update**: The storage is a *CIFS* on a Linux system.

Comment: Hi, tested with local shares (and roughly 30Mb of data) on Windows 10, approach 1 working fine here. Are you working with DFS shares? What is the size of the folder being copied?

Comment: @sodawillow i will ask our server guys what the underlying Server is. The folder has currently 347 MB with 8.464 files.

Comment: What kind of share you are using . Does the User having full permission on that folder where you are recursively taking the data. The first one works fine in my local . Could you please elaborate a little more to analyze  the issue

Comment: @RanadipDutta what kinds of shares do you mean? The user performing the action does NOT have "Full Control" Permission. The user has "Modify" Permission. What else shoul I elaborate? I will try to provide all the Information.

Comment: I got it. What I want to know is if its a normal shared folder then the first approach is working. May be you can post the folder structure so that I can replicate the same. Because when I tried with -recursive it copied the entire trunk. Permission what I believed is may be the use with which you are running the powershell may be not having full permission to write/read. BUt you have mentioned that you do have a modify permission so its fine. Just suggest you to run the *script/ ps console* in elevated mode and see the result once more